# Changing cursor on mouse-over not working on Windows App

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps

I am working on a Windows Store App using `C#`.

I am trying to change the cursor when the user hover over a rectangle but it is causing me problems.

Here is my code:

```
Rectangle item = sender as Rectangle;
item.Cursor = Cursors.AppStarting;
mouseVerticalPosition = e.GetCurrentPoint(null).Position.Y;
mouseHorizontalPosition = e.GetCurrentPoint(null).Position.X;
isMouseCaptured = true;
item.CapturePointer(e.Pointer);
```

It says `'Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle' does not contain a definition for 'Cursor'`.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing WPF with WinRT/XAML. These are both XAML-based UI technologies, but although superficially similar when looking at some basic controls and properties - these are completely separate implementations that have many differences once you start looking at the details. One of these is the `Cursor` property missing in the Windows Runtime.

You can use `Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor` property to get or set the cursor on the current window.

You can also use some attached behaviors I wrote in WinRT XAML Toolkit [here](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/Extensions/FrameworkElementExtensions.cs) to get an API similar to the WPF one where you set a cursor per element. There's a sample you can check [here](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample/Views/Controls.Extensions/FrameworkElementExtensionsCursorTestView.xaml) that shows how you can set a cursor on an element like this:

```
Extensions:FrameworkElementExtensions.SystemCursor="Arrow"
```